# Django acts like user is logged in but isn't

Tags: ajax, django, django-authentication

I have an `AJAX` login in my Django project. The ajax_login `view` gets POST, authenticate user and returns `JsonResponse`. Everything seems to work correct but the user isn't actually logged in.

The weird is that in the view, I'm testing whether the user is logged in and they are.

**VIEW**

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_login_(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

    if user:
        if user.is_authenticated():
            print 'IS LOGGED IN' #THIS IS BEING PRINTED INTO CONSOLE SO USER IS LOGGED IN
            return JsonResponse({'status':0})

    return JsonResponse({'status':1})
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.login-form').find('.submitButton').click(function (e) {
        var next = $(this).closest('.login-form').find('input[name="next"]').val();
        var password = $(this).closest('.login-form').find('#id_password').val();
        var username =$(this).closest('.login-form').find('#id_username').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        var errors = 0;
        if (username == '') {
            $('#id_username_required').show();
            errors += 1;
        } else {
            $('#id_username_required').hide();
        }
        if (password == '') {
            $('#id_password_required').show();
            errors += 1;
        } else {
            $('#id_password_required').hide();
        }

        if (errors == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/login/',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'password': password,
                    'username': username,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 0) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('.login-modal-credentials-incorrect').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Can't figure out where is the problem. It suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Have you debugged your JS in browser, to see, what response you actually receive ?

Comment: Yes, It returns status:0 which is good.

Comment: What does this authenticate() function return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, as usual, very simple. I accidentaly removed `login(request,user)` line after `authenticate` so user has been authenticated but not logged in.

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to call `login()` after `authenticate()`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def ajax_login_(request):
    ...
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

See the docs on [how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is in your js code, where you are reloading your current page. Rather than that, I believe, you must be redirecting to the landing page/home page to the user, if user have been authenticated successfully.

Eg.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/login/',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'password': password,
                'username': username,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == 0) {
                    window.location = "http://yourhost/landing-url"
                } else {
                    $('.login-modal-credentials-incorrect').show();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```